# python deleting specific lines from a string that contain specific expressions

Tags: python

i have the following string/text

```
streets_and_names = '''
#
street 49
 description someone lives there
 name Paul
#
street 51
 description no one lives there
 name no name
#
street 43
 description someone lives there
 name Mark
#
street 42
 description no one lives there
 name no name
#
'''
```

and i would like to get an output by removing the following lines from it

```
 description no one lives there
 name no name
```

and keeping the rest as it is.

does anyone has any idea?

thank you.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: do you want to remove only those lines or including the street number also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your example was literal and just did `res = streets_and_names.replace(' description no one lives there\n name no name', '')`, you would get the result you want.

result:

```py
'''
#
street 49
 description someone lives there
 name Paul
#
street 51
#
street 43
 description someone lives there
 name Mark
#
street 42
#
'''
```